# ORDER BY in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, php

I am filtering my data with:

```
$sel_query="Select * from details where account_id=".$_SESSION['admin_id'];
```

I want to display records in descending order by using query:

```
$sel_query="Select * from details where account_id=".$_SESSION['admin_id'] 
ORDER BY time DESC;
```

Both queries working separately. When I write two conditions, the query is not working.
What do I need to change here?

Comment: Show us your query with the 2 conditions please.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your PHP is invalid. Shouldn't the second line be more like?

```
$sel_query="Select * from details where account_id=".$_SESSION['admin_id']." ORDER BY time DESC";
```